# TypeScript tuple with array element

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

TypeScript newbie here. I did some quick searching but was unable to find an answer.  The question is this: what is the proper definition for an array of tuples, where the first tuple element is a string, and the next is an array of numbers? I've tried this:

```
type labeledValuesType = [string, number[]]

 constructor(headings: string[], rows: Array<labeledValuesType>) {...
```

But in VS Code, when I hover over the second parameter (rows) passed to the constructor call, I see:

```
const rows: (string | number[])[][]
```

which looks like a two-dimensional array of the union of string and number[].

Comment: Could you provide a true [mcve] which demonstrates the issue?  Reproducing the issue in a standalone environment like [the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//) is a good way to know that we're all on the same page.  As it stands, the type of `rows` in your code shows as `(parameter) rows: [string, number[]][]` in my IDE.  Perhaps you are looking at the type of some variable you haven't included in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array of tuple, which have

- a string as first element,
- an array of number as second element

If I'm not wrong on what you're searching:

```js
type MyTuple = [string, number[]];

const myArray: MyTuple[] = [
    ['str', [1, 2, 3]]
];
```

So your code seems OK, your issue concerns more VS code.

Comment: I think the problem in the original code is that `Array<labeledValuesType>` takes a type (`labeledValuesType`) that is already an array, then wraps it in another `Array<>`?